# I want to count how many requests were cancelled per month

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

And show them as a total for each month.  I use the following script

```
SELECT datepart(yy,j.CompletedAt) as 'YY',  
       str(datepart(MM, j.CompletedAt),2) as 'MM', 
       Datename(MM,j.CompletedAt) as 'Month', 
       count('MM') as 'PMInMonth'
FROM facts_reactive.dbo.jobs j 
WHERE (
       (J.Reactive = -1)     
         AND datepart(yy,j.CompletedAt) = ' 2013'
         AND j.jobstatus = 6
       )
GROUP BY datepart(yy,j.CompletedAt),  
         str(datepart(MM, j.CompletedAt),2), 
         Datename(MM,j.CompletedAt)
ORDER BY datepart(yy,j.CompletedAt) ASC,  
         str(datepart(MM, j.CompletedAt),2) ASC;
```

However, if there were no jobs cancelled in the month it does not return anything; whereas I would like the month and 0 returned as the number of cancelled jobs.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: And the version too please

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cMONTHS AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('20130101' AS date) AS TheMonthStart,
        CAST('20130201' AS date) AS TheMonthEnd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(mm, 1, TheMonthStart),
        DATEADD(mm, 1, TheMonthEnd)
    FROM cMONTHS
    WHERE TheMonthStart < '20140101'
)
SELECT
   datepart(yy,c.TheMonthStart) as 'YY',  
   str(datepart(MM, c.TheMonthStart),2) as 'MM', 
   Datename(MM,c.TheMonthStart) as 'Month', 
   count(j.CompletedAt) as 'PMInMonth'
FROM
     cMONTHS c
     LEFT JOIN
     facts_reactive.dbo.jobs j ON j.CompletedAt >= c.TheMonthStart AND j.CompletedAt < c.TheMonthEnd
                   AND
                   J.Reactive = -1   
                   AND
                   j.jobstatus = 6
GROUP BY
   datepart(yy,c.TheMonthStart),  
   str(datepart(MM, c.TheMonthStart),2), 
   Datename(MM,c.TheMonthStart)
ORDER BY
   datepart(yy,c.TheMonthStart),  
   str(datepart(MM, c.TheMonthStart),2);
```

Comment: Your `where` clause will negate the `left join`

Comment: Hi Gbn,Thanks for the script.  I have tried it in SQL Server 2008 R2 and it states there is incorrect syntax on line 27 i.e. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
for the line datepart(yy,c.TheMonthStart) as 'YY'   Any ideas?

Comment: @gbn  Am I doing this wrong, as I cut and paste your script and now get the error  Column "cMONTHS.TheMonthStart" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @gbn  The script returns a rowset for January of the following year, can this be limited purely to the selected year giving 12 rows from January to December, inclusive?

Comment: Change  WHERE TheMonthStart < '20140101'

Comment: @gbn  Thanks .. I had initially changed that line to WHERE TheMonthStart < '20121231'.